# Amchart responsive issue

Tags: charts, responsive, amcharts

I am facing issue in AmChart responsiveness.

Please find codepen here: [codepen](http://%60%3Ca%20href=%22https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzdKMm%22%3Ehere%3C/%3E%60)

The x axis labels are visible in wide screen UI.
[image]
But for tab screens, some labels are not visible 
[image]

I  want all labels to be visible in all screens.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mzdKMm codepen link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AmCharts automatically tweaks how many labels are visible in an axis by default due to  [`autoGridCount`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#autoGridCount) being enabled. You can force all labels to be visible by setting it to false and setting the [`gridCount`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/CategoryAxis#gridCount) property equal to the number of data points in your dataProvider.

```
categoryAxis: {
  // ...
  autoGridCount: false,
  gridCount: /* dataProvider size */
}
```